# Configure Flow to ignore "Missing type annotation for ..." errors on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, types, flowtype

I am working on a React Native project in which I want to gradually adopt `flow`. Many components already have `props` and `state` flow types defined. But most of the methods and variables still don't use flow types. When I run `yarn flow` I get thousands of errors saying `Missing type annotation for ...`.

I would like to configure flow to ignore that kind of errors for now. I will add types to everything later on, and those errors will be relevant only when I have fully typed all objects on each js file. But this might take a long time. So, how can I temporarily or selectively disable those error warnings, while keep flow checking the part of my files which are already using the flow types?

Comment: Have you tried to add `//@flow` pragma only to those parts of the code base, that are fully typed https://flow.org/en/docs/usage/#toc-prepare-your-code-for-flow? Alternatively, you can add `//$FlowFixMe`  before the lines where flow errors are shown

Comment: @frontendgirl Thanks for your comment. I have added `//@flow` to all files where I wish to do type checking. But none of those files are completely typed. For instance, the props and state might be typed but the functions declared inside the component class might not. So, my goal is to find a way where I can check only parts of the files that are typed and ignore the parts that aren't typed.  I am putting type checks only on functions and parts of the app which I judge to be critical, leaving the rest to be typed later when I have free time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't turn off specific errors in Flow. There is a tool at the root of the flow repo that can automatically add suppressions:
https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/tool

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any more information on how to use this tool?

Comment: ```
./tool add-comments --bin \`which flow\` --comment "YOUR COMMENT TEXT HERE" --all
```
should be what you want. Don't worry if the `make js` build fails, since you aren't going to depend on the built flow.

Comment: This is still true in 2024? :( Such a shame, applying Flow to an older code-base is virtually impossible due to all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying anyone should do this but... heres how I did it. I had to find another way because the `tool` solution by Jordan wouldn't work for me. Manually call `flow-bin`, parse returned json, and skip any errors you don't care about.

#### flow.js

```js
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile
const flow = require('flow-bin')

const IGNORE_ERROR_CODES = [
  'missing-annot'
]

const isValidError = (error) => !error.error_codes.some(code => IGNORE_ERROR_CODES.includes(code))
 
execFile(flow, ['check', '--json'], (err, stdout) => {

  if (!stdout) {
    console.error(err, stdout)
    process.exit(1)
  }

  const result = JSON.parse(stdout)
  const errors = result.errors.filter(isValidError)
  const hasErrors = errors.length > 0

  if (hasErrors) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(errors, null, 2))
    process.exit(1)
  } else {
    console.log('Flow passed')
    process.exit(0)
  }

})
```

#### package.json script

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "flow": "node flow.js"
    }
}
```